# submit value when checkbox is checked in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to send values from the form which values are checked .
 Here is my codepen http://codepen.io/surajkhanal/pen/PbPGgJ

```js
angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic'])
.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
  
})
```

```css
.button-dark{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Multiple input</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic app</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form id="valueForm" ng-submit="saveValues(values)">
      <div class="small-input list padding" style="padding-top:4px;">

        <label class="item item-input">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.first">
      <ion-checkbox  ng-model="success.first"  ng-disabled="!values.first" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;" class="checkbox-royal"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.first && values.first" >
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.second" >
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.second" ng-disabled="!values.second" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.second && values.second" >
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.third">
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.third" ng-disabled="!values.third" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.third && values.third">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.four">
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.four" ng-disabled="!values.four" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.four && values.four">
     <input type="text" ng-model="values.five">
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.five" ng-disabled="!values.five" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

       

        <button type="submit" ng-show="success.first" class="button button-dark button-shadow pull-right" style="">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

And the another problem is when i fill the data to the field and unchecked the checkbox the input field hides . How to prevent this problem?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario in which situation the input box should shown and when the check box can be checked?

Comment: @PitchiahNatarajan The scenario is that , as in the snippet i want to send value only which are checked.And there is also one issue , when i checked two more checkbox and if i unchecked the previous one next one is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic'])
.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.saveValues = function(values, checked){
      console.log(values, checked);    
   angular.forEach(checked,function(value, key){
       if(value){
          angular.forEach(values, function(v,k){
            if(key == k && value){
              console.log(key , v)
            }
         })
       }    
    })   
  };
})
```

```css
.button-dark{
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Multiple input</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic app</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <form id="valueForm" ng-submit="saveValues(values,success)">
      <div class="small-input list padding" style="padding-top:4px;">

        <label class="item item-input">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.first">
      <ion-checkbox  ng-model="success.first"  ng-disabled="!values.first" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;" class="checkbox-royal"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.first && values.first" >
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.second" >
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.second" ng-disabled="!values.second" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.second && values.second" >
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.third">
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.third" ng-disabled="!values.third" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.third && values.third">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="values.four">
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.four" ng-disabled="!values.four" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="success.four && values.four">
     <input type="text" ng-model="values.five">
     <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-royal" ng-model="success.five" ng-disabled="!values.five" style="border: none;padding-left: 30px;"></ion-checkbox>
   </label>

       

        <button type="submit" ng-show="success.first" class="button button-dark button-shadow pull-right" style="">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know this things but i here want to check if the value which is checked should only send to the controller.

Comment: check once @SurazKhanal